# Issue with objects in java?

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface

I am making a window that reacts based on user input of yes or no. I am running into an issue in this part of the code:

```
public class Mywindow {

public static void main (String [] args){
    windowcontinued object = new windowcontinued();
    object.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //ISSUE HERE
    object.setSize(700, 1024); //ISSUE HERE
    object.setVisible(true); //ISSUE HERE
                                         }
                }
```

These simple operations should make sure the program terminates when closed, is a certain size, and is visible. For some reason though, on all three operations I am getting errors saying:

```
 The method setDefaultCloseOperation(int) is undefined for the type windowcontinued

The method setSize(int, int) is undefined for the type windowcontinued

The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type windowcontinued
```

Although, all of these should have already been defined after importing. Here is the full code:

Main code:

```
package Myguipackage;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Mywindow {

public static void main (String [] args){
    windowcontinued object = new windowcontinued();
    object.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    object.setSize(700, 1024);
    object.setVisible(true);

                                         }
                }
```

Other class:

```
package Myguipackage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Windowcontinued{

public JLabel text;
public JTextField textfield;

public windowcontinued(){  //Constructor
/*  super("CHAT");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());   */   

    text = new JLabel ("Would you like to talk to me?");
        text.add(text);

    textfield = new JTextField ("Yes or no? Erase this and type in your answer!");




                   }






 class hear implements ActionListener{



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        String string = "";

        if(event.getSource()==textfield)
            string = String.format("You typed in %s", event.getActionCommand());

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string); //Open a new window that displays String string, which has changed based on which field you hit enter on.




                                                  }



                                         }


                        }
```

After using the extends keyword as suggested by fdsa, here is the new code:

package Myguipackage;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class mywindow extends JFrame{

public static void main (String [] args){
    windowcontinued object = new windowcontinued();
    object.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    object.setSize(700, 1024);
    object.setVisible(true);
                                         }
                }
```

Class windowcontinued is still the same though.

Comment: You should try to respect Java naming convention and your code is barely readable, you should fix that.

Comment: Do you see any of the methods you called, in your `windowcontinued` code? Why do you expect them to be there?

Comment: Those are based on the imports above in the code.

Comment: Windowcontinued or windowcontinued? How do you expect people to help when you don't post the actual code?

Comment: It states "Class windowcontinued is still the same though." Earlier in the post, I have class windowcontinued already posted, the end part is just the same code, but with extends. This is all written in the post itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other posters said, please follow the java naming conventions when naming your classes. It makes your code a easier to follow.

You seem to be confused as to the purpose of `import` statement. When you import an object, you can only use its methods on objects of that type. If you would like your class to mimic the functionality of an existing class, you need to `extend` the original class, not just `import` it.

Comment: Do you mean like this: public class mywindow extends JFrame{ , because that is not working either. Feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, `MyWindow` should extend `JFrame`.

Comment: Even after doing this though, those errors continue to exist. How should I resolve them?

Comment: Please update the question with your code that uses `extends`

Comment: OK -- you're supposed to extend the other class. While I appreciate your effort at posting code/solving this problem, I think there are too many concepts that you don't understand for me to be of any help. I would suggest that you take some time to read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/. After that a lot of this will make more sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86927/discussion-between-rich-and-fdsa).